# What is an easier word than “serendipity” with the same connotations

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

A word that a majority of high schoolers would know.
Unless, of course, there is significant evidence that most high-schoolers know the word “serendipity”.

It shows up somewhere between 35,000 and 36,000 most frequent words: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/PG/2006/04/30001-40000

Comment: There isn't one. Why would you want it anyway?

Comment: For a marketing slogan.

Comment: A [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/serendipity) is useful for such matters.

Comment: General Reference. Personally, I'd just use *serendipity* anyway (how are kids going to learn "hard" words if people don't use them?) - but if you want to be patronising, just say **luck** (I don't need to be told about the difference between "luck" and "serendipity", btw! :)

Comment: Though it's not just one word, if you must make a substitution, I like "good fortune."

Comment: It's not a single word, but ***stumble upon*** is a phrase high schoolers would know. And there's a popular website by that name, which helps you make serendipitous discoveries on the web: http://www.stumbleupon.com/

Comment: Did a thesaurus suggest 'good luck'?

Comment: @Mitch I do not know why it is that when you write for kids still in school, that you can use words of just one <CENSORED>, but it is not to hard once you get used to it. As long as you steer clear of words that come from Welsh and Scots, and keep them short, you will not piss them off when they learn how dumb they are. See, this text is all in such words, and you can go on like this for quite some time if you take some small bit of care.

Comment: Fortuitous - doesn't Noun'erise well :-). Fortunate.

Comment: @tchrist:  nice! But really Scots? cwm/coomb, Bairn, wee, loch, dram,  whisky fecking galore oops is that Irish? Wait...are there polysyllabic words in English from Scots/Welsh?

Comment: @Mitch - Does a passive-aggressive approach to conveying learning commend itself?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: No, it suggests I can't read, given that I only just noticed that someone already mentioned a thesaurus.

Comment: Barrie England's answer that "There isn't one" should be considered significant and the post can be archived for future. It helps plenty of people, plus it can also move in due course to ELL to benefit them even more.

Comment: Fluke, happy coincidence, etc, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Happenstance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happenstance)* (“A chance or random event or circumstance”) is another well-known word that might work.
Regarding *[coincidence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coincidence)*, the collocation *happy coincidence* is not uncommon, and might interchange with serendipity.

Comment: but wait ... high-schoolers don't know "serendipity" (one of the most popular spaceships in fiction!) but they **would know 'happenstance'?????????**

Comment: Wait I've got one!  Since these kids don't know their Walpole, what about **"jungian synchronicity"**?  It's not exactly the same but close enough!

Answer (score 2):

`Fluke` comes to mind: it means "A stroke of good luck" and implies happenstance.

And of course: `coincidence` though that does not connote *happy* or *positive*.

Comment: coincidence feels close. The fairly positive connotation of serendipity was definitely the goal, but I've been getting a surprising number of blank stares when the word 'serendipity' comes up.

Answer (score 1):

***Serendipity*** just means ***luck***, albeit in a good way not a bad one.

If “most high-schoolers don’t know *serendipity”*, well then perhaps they need to spend more time in school; it is, after all, a fairly unremarkable word. As Vlad is wont to say: *I assure you, in the small fishing village I come from it forms the sole topic of conversation of grade-schooler and fish monger alike.*

Comment: May I ask who is "Vlad"?